# Checking the validity of email format HTML input

Tags: php, validation, email

I have an input field to enter an email address as follows:

```
 <input type="email" name="email" id="email" title="E-mail(Format: email@example.com)">
```

I want to check the validity of this when user submits the email address. So i used this code:

```
 <?php
 $email =($_POST['email']);
 if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
 {
 echo "E-mail is not valid";
 }
else
{
 echo "E-mail is valid"; }? >
```

But although i enter an email as 'someone@example' this will print 'email is valid'. How can i validate the emails with 'someone@example.com' format? That means the format and the need of '@' and '.com' ?

Comment: [**Really**](http://codepad.org/yCkItJxz) ???

Comment: :O but in my browser it is printed as email is valid!

Comment: When you have fully working awesome solution what else do you want?

Comment: But in my GoogleChrome browser it is printed as valid!!

Comment: I think thats a bug, what php version are you using?

Comment: No im using PHP 5.3.1

Comment: Post the value you getting in `$email`.

Comment: Well here you go even in 5.3 dev its working fine: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zUtcor
Though there was problem in php 5.2.13 and lesser version regarding this.

Comment: Here is my code after removing other parts. `<html><body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" title="E-mail(Format: email@example.com)">
<button type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
$h=($_POST['email']);
echo $h;
if(!filter_var($h, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
  {
  echo "E-mail is not valid";
  }
else
  {
  echo "E-mail is valid";
  }}
?>
</body></html>`

Comment: Enter 'someone@example' for this and see. I get it as valid

Comment: @dnk you are wrong no problem with code, its working fine for me and everywhere.

Comment: @dnk how about running this code in browser and tell us details:

echo phpversion();

Comment: 5.3.1 will be printed.

Comment: This worked fine in Firefox. But not working in Google Chrome. Then is it something wrong with the Chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use an e-mail regular expressions and PHP function preg_match https://www.php.net/preg_match.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this function

```
public static function isEmail($value)
  {
    $atom = "[-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]"; // RFC 5322 unquoted characters in local-part
    $localPart = "(?:\"(?:[ !\\x23-\\x5B\\x5D-\\x7E]*|\\\\[ -~])+\"|$atom+(?:\\.$atom+)*)"; // quoted or unquoted
    $alpha = "a-z\x80-\xFF"; // superset of IDN
    $domain = "[0-9$alpha](?:[-0-9$alpha]{0,61}[0-9$alpha])?"; // RFC 1034 one domain component
    $topDomain = "[$alpha](?:[-0-9$alpha]{0,17}[$alpha])?";
    return (bool) preg_match("(^$localPart@(?:$domain\\.)+$topDomain\\z)i", $value);
}
```

Its from Nette framework and its the best function for email validation ive ever seen.

https://github.com/nette/nette/blob/master/Nette/Utils/Validators.php

Comment: This is not a solution its an alternate.

Comment: It is. But its obviously a little better then filter_var :)